# Can I always by default have Title Region for Site Page set as 'Plain'?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, page-layout, modern-pages, sitepages

When creating a new page, it always needs to be set as 'Plain' for Title Section.

Can I achieve this and how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another method by using content type.

Here are steps:

1.In the Pages library -> Create a page with Plain layout.

2.Go to Site settings -> Site content types -> Create a new content type.

[image]

3.In the newly created content type -> Advanced settings -> Use an existing template  -> Enter the URL of the site page (Step 1).

[image]

4.Go to Pages library -> Add the newly created content type.

5.Then create new pages by using newly created content type.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online modern experience site pages, you can achieve this using **Page templates**.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint site and create a new page with "Plain" title region
2. When your page looks the way you want, Save it as draft, then click the down arrow next to **Save** at the top of the page, and click **Save as template**.
3. Set a template as a default selection in the Template pane: You can either do it from SharePoint UI or using PowerShell

   - SharePoint UI:

     [image]
   - PowerShell: [Set a page template as default page template in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/05/26/set-a-page-template-as-default-page-template-in-sharepoint-online/)
4. Always create new pages using this new page template: From SharePoint site home page --> New --> Page

**Microsoft Documentation**: [Page templates in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873)